# Adding labels to Dataframe from node attributes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx

I am trying to create a Dataframe with Pandas that displays different measures of centrality inside a network of rappers. I am trying to add their names to the dataframe while keeping the index intact, so that there is the possibility to look them up by number and name. I am unable to add the names to a distinct column.

I am using python3, networkx and pandas. Since I am fairly new to programming all of my attempts resulted in compiling errors. Here is what I have tried so far:

This is my shortened dataframe. 'G' is a graphobject, which is assigned the nodes and edges of my data.

```py
rapper_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': dict(name),  
                          'Degree': dict(nx.degree(G))})
```

This is my attempt to add the labels to a separate dict to add to the df.

```py
name_undict = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'label')
name = []
name.append(name_undict)
```

The dict looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvgoq.png

I expected a dataframe with an index, 2 columns ('Name' and 'Degree') and the corresponding data inside the rows (e.g.: 1 - Snoop Dogg - 4), but I get the compile error on line 1 for the rapper_df section of the code.

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5214; 2 is required

Since I am fairly new to this, I am more or less at my wits end. Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Best Regards, 
Ranga

Comment: Can you please add, for which line you get this error and also, what `G` is in your code?

Comment: I edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score -1):

You probably want the following:

```
attr_dict = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'label')
deg_dict = dict(nx.degree(G))

combined = [(name, deg) for (name, deg) in zip(attr_dict.values(),
            deg_dict.values()) if attr_dict.keys() == deg_dict.keys()]
rapper_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [name[0] for name in combined],  
                          'Degree': [deg[1] for deg in combined]})
```

Comment: Don't worry. I was also downvoted without any notice. And I think voting shouldn't just be done based on if code runs or not btw. I think SO should change the policy regarding downvotes. They should only be possible if a comment is left, otherwise it is just demotivation. You don't write long explanations and work for someone, you don't know if you even get punished for it in the end.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I just got around to testing it. Sadly it doesnt seem to work, I only receive the correct column names, but without any data inside of it.
And regarding the downvoting, @jottbe I dont know who downvoted you, I am thankful for your explanation regarding dicts and their limitations. Sadly my upvotes wont show up, since I dont have enough rep.

Comment: This is most likely due to the `if attr_dict.keys() == deg_dict.keys()` condition. You need to ensure that the order of `keys()` is the same in both `attr_dict` and `deg_dict` - then it will work.

Comment: They seem to be in the same order, or am I missing something? [link](https://i.imgur.com/kXPOqcD.png)